# Apache camel soap request type conversion error

Tags: java, soap, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I'm trying to send a soap request in apache camel running on an osgi enviroment (karaf). Until now I got this code

```
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "START");

    MyRouteBuilder routeBuilder = new MyRouteBuilder();
    camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();

    StreamComponent stream = new StreamComponent();
    camelContext.addComponent("stream", stream);

    camelContext.addRoutes(routeBuilder);

    CxfComponent cxf = new CxfComponent();
    camelContext.addComponent("cxf", cxf);

    try {
        ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate(0);
        camelContext.start();
        String url = "cxf://http://some.server/webservice?"
                + "wsdlURL=http://some.server/webservice?wsdl&"
                + "serviceName={http://some.server}Service&"
                + "portName={http://some.server}ServiceSoapPort"
                + "&dataFormat=MESSAGE";
        Exchange e = sendSimpleMessage(template, url);
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, e.getOut().getBody().toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "ERROR: ");
    }

}

public void stop(BundleContext context) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "STOP");

    try {
        camelContext.stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, e.toString());
    }

}

private static Exchange sendSimpleMessage(ProducerTemplate template,
        String endpointUri) {

    final List<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    headers.put(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, "authenticate");
    headers.put("requestObject", new DefaultCxfBinding());
    params.add("hello world");

    Exchange exchange = template.request(endpointUri, new Processor() {
        public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = createSOAPRequest();

            soapMessage.setContentDescription("someId");
            soapMessage.setProperty("key", "value");
            soapMessage.setProperty("key", "value");
            soapMessage.setProperty("key", "value");

            soapMessage.setContentDescription("");
            soapMessage.setProperty("key", "value");

            exchange.getIn().setBody(soapMessage.getSOAPBody());
        }
    });
    return exchange;

}

private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    String serverURI = "http://some.server";

    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("", serverURI);

    javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("getApplication",
            "example");

    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://some.server/someFunction");

    soapMessage.saveChanges();

    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, soapMessage.toString());

    return soapMessage;
}
```

And now I got this error in my karaf logs

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentExcetion: Could not find a suitable setter for property: portName as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: javax.xml.namespace.QName with value [...]
```

And the same happens for serviceName when I delete portName - So how is it possible to pass these arguments as javax.xml.namespace.QName? Or is there anything else I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Getting the same error when I simplify it to this

```
        from("direct:start")
            .process(new Processor() {

                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getIn().setBody("<mandant>001</<mandant>");
                }
            })
            .to("cxf://http://some.server/webservice?"
            + "wsdlURL=http://some.server/webservice?wsdl&"
            + "serviceName={http://some.server}Service&"
            + "portName={http://some.server}ServiceSoapPort"
            + "&dataFormat=MESSAGE")
            .to("file:C:/output?fileName=soap.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

The TypeConverter that you need is [CxfConverter](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.15.x/components/camel-cxf/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/cxf/converter/CxfConverter.java) It is normally loaded to CamelContext by Spring or Blueprint using [AnnotationTypeConverterLoader](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/impl/converter/AnnotationTypeConverterLoader.html). You can add TypeConverters to CamelContext like [this](http://camel.apache.org/type-converter.html) but it only works on classes that implement TypeConverter interface but CxfConverter is @Converter annotated and it should be found using discovery.

I don't know how to solve this but I hope you get further with this information. Please update here if you figure this out.