# Apache Camel on Karaf missing requirement soap

Tags: java, maven, soap, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I'm trying to do a soap request using camel-soap. It is packaged as a bundle and gets deployed on karaf. I use maven and got this dependeny in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-soap</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I also installed camel-soap on karaf.

Code for the Request looks like this

```
        from("timer:testTimer?period=1000")
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("key", "value");
                    exchange.getOut().setBody(params);
                }
            })
            .to("soap:testWebservice?wsdlUrl=" + WSDL + "&serviceAddress="
                    + ADDRESS + "&operationName=authenticate")
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    Map body = (Map) exchange.getIn().getBody();
                    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, body.toString());
                }
            });
```

In my Activator class I'm creating DefaultCamelContext on my own but there is no SoapComponent or something like this I could add to my camel context to make this work.

Anyone can help me out?

Comment: camel-soap installs just soap dataformat. I don't think you can use it in a uri like that. Do you have a link to some reference where it's shown that you can use it like .to("soap:testWebService...") ? Btw, the topic of your question doesn't seem to match the content of the question, is there a mistake there?

Comment: I regret searching for "camel soap" in google

Comment: I got the example for that from https://code.google.com/p/camel-soap/wiki/Introduction - I also tried it with cxf but there im facing some problems that I need to pass the serverName and portName as QName but only got it as String: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517237/apache-camel-soap-request-type-conversion-error

Comment: The example uses different camel-soap library from com.wfreitas. See the Apache camel-soap documentation [here](http://camel.apache.org/soap.html). I don't think it is supposed to work in a way you have used it since it's just a dataformat.